# GitLab postfix configuration mail not sending

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab

I installed GitLab on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. Now I can login as an Administrator, do some stuffs, however, my question is the email seems to be not workin. I need to confirm the confirmation email sent to my address.

I installed postfix as per instruction by our the readme. How can I test my postfix or configure GitLab configuration.

Answer (score 6):

In case your ISP is blocking port 25 (this happens apparently quite often and was the case for me as well) you can use Gmail as a Relay. The following instructions are from [here](http://www.shellhacks.com/en/Postfix-Gmail-as-Relay-Linux-Mint-Ubuntu-Debian) and walk you step-by-step through the process:

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` add:

```
# Relaying Postfix SMTP via GMAIL
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Then you need to setup the Gmail credentials. For this open/create `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and write:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587    USERNAME@gmail.com:PASSWORD
```

Where (as you might have guessed) `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` are your credentials. Then change permissions for the file:

```
$ sudo chmod 400 /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Now we need to add the certificate to Postfix:

```
$ cat /etc/ssl/certs/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem | sudo tee -a /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
```

Just restart postfix and you should be good:

```
$ sudo service postfix restart
```

If you want to test:

```
$ echo "Hello World" | mail -s "Test Message" you@example.com
```

And check what the mail log thinks about it:

```
$ tail /var/log/mail.log
```

*Note*: You only have 500 emails per day using Gmail's SMTP Server as Relay.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. it complains  `connect to smtp.gmail.com[173.194.72.109]:587: Connection refused`

Comment: That Thawte thing is a key authority?

Comment: What if I don't have the `Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem`?

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue with the same OS but on VMWare.

How I solved it:
1 - Checked this post and checked step 3 from user3085707's answer:

> try from command line to send a email and check your logs http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/01/how-to-send-email-from-the-linux-command-line/

2 -"mail" command was not installed and ubuntu said:

> The program 'mail' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt-get install mailutils

So I did it ("Ubuntu should know what he is doing", I thought).

3 - In the next settings I selected "Internet site" (or something like it) and entered a domain (in my case I used "code.repo");

4 - Tested "mail" command. It was working (even though the mail was sent to the spam folder);

5 - Created new user in Gitlab. Checked my mail.

6 - Thanked the almighty Ubuntu for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Can be many reasons for you problem..

1. check your mail log (more /var/log/mail.log)
2. if you use iptables make sure that you dont blocking port 25 (sudo ufw allow 25)
3. try from command line to send a email and check your logs
   http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/12/01/how-to-send-email-from-the-linux-command-line/
4. Check with your ISP,  may blocking the port 25

Answer (score 0):

if you have the problem:
`cat: /etc/ssl/certs/Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem: No such file or directory`

you can fix it by following:

```bash
$ cd /etc/ssl/certs/
$ sudo wget https://www.thawte.com/roots/thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem
$ sudo mv thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem Thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem
```

Reference: [Managing Postfix Mail Server Linux Systems Archives - VPSHELPDESK.COM](https://vpshelpdesk.com/category/managing-postfix-mail-server-linux-systems/)